# I am trying to migrate Exchange On premise distribution lists to 365 using this powershell script but I am running into this issue

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server, distribution-list

I am trying to push this powershell script to migrate the On premise exchange distribution lists to 365 but running into an error I have posted a screen shot of the error and script below.

```
#Connect to Exchange Online
#Connect-ExchangeOnline

#Source - Provide the name of the on-prem distribution group you wish to migrate
$DistGroup = "test group"

#To avoid naming conflicts, we will append the word copy to the end of the migrate distribution group name
$Append = "copy"

#Name for the new cloud distribution group
$CloudGroup = "$DistGroup $Append"

#Import the csv file with all of the on-prem distribution groups
#Target the on-prem distribution group you wish to copy
$DistGroupCSV = Import-csv -path "\\vhall02\it\GADGroup\projects\distribution list\dlist.csv" | where-object {$_."display name" -eq $DistGroup}
$DistGroupname = $DistGroupCSV.'DISPLAY NAME'
$c = Get-DistributionGroup -identity $DistGroupname
$smtpaddresses = $c.EmailAddresses
New-DistributionGroup -Name $CloudGroup -Type "distribution"
$var = '@{Add='
foreach ($smtpaddress in $smtpaddresses){
$var = $var+ '"'+$smtpaddress+'",'
}
$var = $var.substring(0,$var.length-1)
$var = $var+ '}'
Set-DistributionGroup -Identity $CloudGroup -EmailAddresses $var
Get-DistributionGroup $CloudGroup | format-table
```

I tried running this script but no success

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXMWd.png)

Comment: The Command New-DistributionGroup is failing.  First check the value of $CloudGroup to make sure it is valid.  The exception says you do not have WRITE access to the command.  You may need to run the script as an Admin by right click PS shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Comment: Try `Set-DistributionGroup -Identity $CloudGroup -EmailAddresses @{Add=[string[]]$smtpaddresses}`

Comment: @jdweng I am already a system admin and Theo I tried your line and it produced a different error this time showing error: There are multiple smtp addresses. Please ensure there is only one primary address for each address type.

Comment: See following : https://cloudblue.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/44001883366-task-to-update-exchange-mailbox-fails-there-are-multiple-primary-smtp-addresses-?force_isolation=true

Comment: No luck @jdweng :(

Comment: Did you run on "Active Directory domain controller"?  Since you are working with groups are all user in the group on the same controller?

Answer (score 0):

There are several messages rolled up in the error you've received:

```
 1. Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'EmailAddresses'.
 2. Cannot convert value [...] to type "Microsoft.Exchange.Data.ProxyAddressCollection"
 3. The address [...] is invalid: the address prefix (type) cannot exceed 9 characters.
```

These messages help identify where to look. In the first message, `parameter 'EmailAddresses'` can only refer to the `Set-DistributionGroup` command, as that's the only place it appears in your script. Here we see that the variable "`$var`" is the value reported to this parameter. The second message indicates that the value reported (i.e. `$var`) is not of the correct data type and cannot be converted.

Tracing back to see how `$var` is built, a likely problem immediately presents itself: `$var` has been created as a Hashtable `@{}`. A Hashtable, however, is an unnecessary construct in this use case; a simple Array `@()` is more correctly suited.

Try this:

```
# Replace lines 20 - 25 in your script with the following:
$var = '@('          #<- Change curly brace to parenthesis and remove "Add="
foreach ($smtpaddress in $smtpaddresses){
  $var = $var + '"' + $smtpaddress + '",'
}
$var = $var.substring(0,$var.length-1)
$var = $var + ')'    #<- Change curly brace to parenthesis again here
```

The reason why this is important is that an Array is a collection of individual items, whereas a Hashtable is a set of key/value pairs (See [here](https://tommymaynard.com/there-is-a-difference-arrays-versus-hash-tables/) for an excellent discussion on the differences between the two). To quote from the aforementioned linked resource *(emphasis mine)*:

> "Arrays and [Hashtables] are both data structures. They can both hold
> multiple values, and they can both be stored in a single variable. The
> difference is keys and values. Arrays hold **single items** in each index,
> while a hash table holds a **key-value pair** in each."

As such, in this particular case, we have no need of "key/value *pairs*" -- rather, we simply need a list (or "collection") of the *individual* SMTP addresses to pass to `Set-DistributionGroup` as the value for the parameter `-EmailAddresses`.

An Array is exactly what's called for, and thus the correct construct to use.

Comment: I tried that script and ran into another error the error that displayed is this Write-ErrorMessage : ExC71195|Microsoft.Exchange.Data.DataValidationException|There is no primary SMTP address.
At C:\Users\vrxp01\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpEXO_4c4hpjz5.rfa\tmpEXO_4c4hpjz5.rfa.psm1:1120 char:13